# How does Object have more functions than an actual object?

Tags: javascript

I'm confused why `var obj = {};` or `var obj = new Object();` then `obj.getOwnPropertySymbols` is undefined??

---

[image: example 1]

---

[image: example 2]

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: this is in chrome, not sure what version

Comment: How exactly are you doing it in chrome?

Comment: `CMD+Option+J` or `Control+Shift+J` on PC

Comment: browsers still have some deprecated methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object` itself has some methods defined, such as [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).  These aren't defined on `Object.prototype`, so they're not available on object instances.

Comment: dang, yea i don't know how this wasn't obvious to me, very strange to not put helper functions on the prototype

Comment: Nah it's not.  If that happened you'd be unable to define a method called `keys()` for example, it would be a nightmare for backwards compatibility

Answer (score 3):

Constructors have two separate kinds of methods:

- Prototypical methods

  Defined as properties of `Constructor.prototype`, the are only available on instances.
- Static methods

  Defined as properties of `Constructor` itself, the are only available on the constructor.

ES6 classe make it clear

```
class Constructor {
  static foo() { return 123; }
  bar() { return 456; }
}
Constructor.foo(); // 123
Constructor.bar;   // undefined
new Constructor().foo; // undefined
new Constructor().bar; // 456
```

Your case is special, however: the static methods of the `Object` constructor seem to include the prototypical methods. But that's because `Object` inherits from `Object.prototype`.

The prototypical chains are like

- `Object` instance

  ```
  instance -> Object.prototype -> null
  ```
- `Object` constructor

  ```
  Object -> Function.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null
  ```

Comment: Haha, you just had to explain it better than me +1

Answer (score 1):

Technically, `Object` (the constructor) is not of the type `object`, it's a class/function depending on what term you want to using with JS. Because it's a class, it has methods on it that are not used in instances of that object. IE: they're not on the returned objects prototype.

In your Chrome console, try this:

```
var obj = {};
typeof obj; // "object"
typeof Object; // "function"
```

Look into the way class prototyping works in JS when you get a chance.

To clarify a bit, when you run `new Object()` it returns something with the type of `object` that has the necessary methods on it.

I think this is a good reference of what I'm talking about: [JavaScript - The Good Parts: Function prototypes vs Object prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321962/javascript-the-good-parts-function-prototypes-vs-object-prototypes)

You can see the same behavior with `Number` and `String`. The **types** of both are actually `function`, but once they're created, you get one of the type of `number` or `string`, each with their relevant prototype methods.

**The bottom line is the constructor is not the same as the returned value.**

Comment: what about Strings or Numbers?

Comment: @JordanHendrix Actually it's not.

Comment: that sentence is why I Dv'd and now its gone, relax dude - I meant the same thing Oriol did

Comment: @JordanHendrix It's all good man. I just like to have feedback with DV, I put a lot of thought into my answers, so if it's wrong, I'd like to know why. In your case, I understand, still not sure what the DVs are for.